# Cant get Table per Type (TPT) Inheritance Strategy - Code First Migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework, migration, ef-fluent-api

I have the class

```
public class Company
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DeactivatedOn { get; set; }
    public DateTime? UpdatedOn { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}

public class Supplier : Company
{
    public int ContactId { get; set; }
    public int DocumentId { get; set; }
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
}
```

These are the mappings

```
public class CompanyMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Company>
{
    public CompanyMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        HasKey(c => c.Id);

        //Table  
        ToTable("Company");

    }
}

public class SupplierMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Supplier>
{
    public SupplierMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        HasKey(s => s.Id);

        // Properties

        //Relationship
        HasRequired(s => s.Company)
            .WithMany().HasForeignKey(c => c.CompanyId);

        //Table  
        ToTable("Supplier");

    }
}
```

This is the context

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CompanyMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new SupplierMap());
    }


    public DbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Supplier> Suppliers { get; set; }

}
```

Seeding:

```
        var companies = new List<Company>
        {
            new Company {Id = 1,  Name = "X", CreatedOn = DateTime.Now, IsActive = true, UpdatedOn = DateTime.Now},
            new Company {Id = 2,  Name = "XX", CreatedOn = DateTime.Now, IsActive = true, UpdatedOn = DateTime.Now},
            new Company {Id = 3,  Name = "XXX", CreatedOn = DateTime.Now, IsActive = true, UpdatedOn = DateTime.Now},
            new Company {Id = 4,  Name = "XXXX", CreatedOn = DateTime.Now, IsActive = true, UpdatedOn = DateTime.Now},
        };

        foreach (var item in companies)
        {
            context.Companies.AddOrUpdate(item);
        }

        var suppliers = new List<Supplier>
        {
            new Supplier {Id = 1, CreatedOn = DateTime.Now, Company = companies[0], IsActive = true, UpdatedOn  = DateTime.Now},
            new Supplier {Id = 2, CreatedOn = DateTime.Now, Company = companies[1], IsActive = true, UpdatedOn = DateTime.Now},
            new Supplier {Id = 3, CreatedOn = DateTime.Now, Company = companies[2], IsActive = true, UpdatedOn = DateTime.Now},
            new Supplier {Id = 4, CreatedOn = DateTime.Now, Company = companies[3],  IsActive = true, UpdatedOn = DateTime.Now}
        };

        foreach (var item in suppliers)
        {
            context.Suppliers.AddOrUpdate(item);
        }

    this.SaveChanges(context);
```

What I am expecting is 2 tables with all inherited with same properties, (base class and inherited class but I cant this to work, my result is a single table with a [Discriminator] collunn.

Any help is more than welcome.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

To force TPT is enough to specify ToTable so I copied/pasted your code and everything is as expected.

Here the create table statements with EF 6.1.3-40302

```
CREATE TABLE [Company] (
 [Id] int not null identity(1,1)
, [Name] text null
, [CreatedOn] datetime not null
, [DeactivatedOn] datetime null
, [UpdatedOn] datetime null
, [IsActive] bit not null
);
ALTER TABLE [Company] ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_Company_65cc9e90] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])



CREATE TABLE [Supplier] (
 [Id] int not null
, [ContactId] int not null
, [DocumentId] int not null
, [CompanyId] int not null
);
ALTER TABLE [Supplier] ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_Supplier_65cc9e90] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])



CREATE INDEX [IX_Id] ON [Supplier] ([Id])



CREATE INDEX [IX_CompanyId] ON [Supplier] ([CompanyId])



ALTER TABLE [Supplier] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Supplier_Company_Id] FOREIGN KEY ([Id]) REFERENCES [Company] ([Id])



ALTER TABLE [Supplier] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Supplier_Company_CompanyId] FOREIGN KEY ([CompanyId]) REFERENCES [Company] ([Id])
```

Are you sure that this is exactly the code you run? There was a mistake on the code so it is possible that your original code was different...